# is my C# standard deviation code correct?

Tags: c#, math, statistics

So I'm trying to compute standard deviation in C# and I got the following code:

```
    double M = 0.0;
    double S = 0.0;
    int period = Values.Length;
    int k;
    double tmpM;
    double value;
    for(int i = 0; i < period; i++){
        tmpM = M;
        value = Values[i];
        k = i + 1;
        M += (value - tmpM) / k;
        S += (value - tmpM) * (value - M);
    }
    stdev = Math.Sqrt(S / (period - 1));
```

where Values is an array of data in which I'm trying to obtain the standard deviation

Do you think my code is correct or did I miss something?

Btw I was trying to implement this: http://www.johndcook.com/standard_deviation.html

Comment: Should probably be on code review

Comment: What seems to be your problem?

Comment: It looks right- is there a specific problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't handle the case where `period == 1` correctly. In that eventuality you will divide by zero.

Otherwise I believe your code to be correct.

Comment: In that case the sample estimate for standard deviation is infinite.

Comment: Following the execution, the first iteration yields the same thing as in the paper.  But I don't like the paper's explanation, I'd go looking for Knuth's presentation of the algorithm.

Comment: @Ben You are right. The code as presented is correct.